# Using data from cell in VBA code to open directory

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Rewording my question:

```
Sub Path()
Dim path As Range
Dim shPivot As Worksheet
Set shPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot")
Set path = shPivot.Range("E12").Value
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open("S:\_Supply Chain\Weekly Rpts Supplier and Buyer\" & path & "\SUPPLIER_01_00028257_KIK CUSTOM PRODUCTS GAINSVILLE_21-OCT-12.xls")
```

Path is a date in a cell. When this cell changes, I want the directory to change according to path.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the main question is.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I reworded my question for simplicity.

Comment: Still not getting it.  You already have the path as a variable in your routine, where is the issue?

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error when I run it. It's highlighting the Set path portion.

Comment: See, that's information that should have been in your original question, how were we supposed to guess that?

Comment: Sorry? I thought it was assumed when someone posts here, there is a problem with the coding =/

Comment: my point is, you never indicated you were getting an error, what error the line was on, or what the error even was.  Details help us figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two Things

1. Declare path as string and not as range.
2. Replace "\" in the date before using it in the path

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim path As String
path = shPivot.Range("E12").Value
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open("S:\_Supply Chain\Weekly Rpts Supplier and Buyer\" & _
              format(path,"DD-MM-YYYY") & _
              "\SUPPLIER_01_00028257_KIK CUSTOM PRODUCTS GAINSVILLE_21-OCT-12.xls")
```

**FOLLOWUP**

In that case use this

```
Dim path As String
path = shPivot.Range("E12").Value
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open("S:\_Supply Chain\Weekly Rpts Supplier and Buyer\" & _
              path & _
              "\SUPPLIER_01_00028257_KIK CUSTOM PRODUCTS GAINSVILLE_21-OCT-12.xls")
```

If there are any unwanted spaces then you will have to use `TRIM`

```
Dim path As String
path = shPivot.Range("E12").Value
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open("S:\_Supply Chain\Weekly Rpts Supplier and Buyer\" & _
              Trim(path) & _
              "\SUPPLIER_01_00028257_KIK CUSTOM PRODUCTS GAINSVILLE_21-OCT-12.xls")
```

Comment: Nope, the value in E12 is the exact value I need. I'm getting a runtime error.

Comment: That is my original code but there is a runtime error and I do not know why.

Comment: `That is my original code but there is a runtime error and I do not know why.` No it is not the original code :) See how path has been declared as string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18603/discussion-between-kmiao91-and-siddharth-rout)